# INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'MemoryError'>,

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am running tensorflow object detection train.py
I am using tensorflow-gpu 1.5, Windows 10, CUDA 9.0, CUDNN 7.0, Python 3.5 with 3* GTX 1070 8GB memory graphic cards.

When I run `python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config`, I get the following error:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'MemoryError'>
```

Even before the training starts

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust the batch_size in the train.py file to address the memory issues.